# Making specific list into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having troubles making a list into a dataframe.

dataInList=

```
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retle ",' 105.0 (C)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retla ",' 0 (s*C)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retla",' 0 (s*C)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retke",' 0 (s)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retds",' 0 (s)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','rewr",' 0 (s)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','sdff",' 0 (s)\n']
```

df = pd.DataFrame(dataInList) only recognizes two of the sample points as columns producing this:

```
                                                   0             1
1  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','..............'   101.5 (C)\n
2  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','..............'   105.0 (C)\n
3  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','..............'   118.0 (C)\n
4  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','..............'   110.0 (C)\n
5  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','..............'   110.0 (C)\n
```

How should I proceed?

Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: each of your sublists only has two elements - look at the placing of the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list` comprehension with `split` first values of lists and then add `strip` for remove trailing whitespaces:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[y.strip() for y in x[0].split(',') + [x[1]]] for x in dataInList])
print (df)
                           0    1       2       3          4
0  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n'  'A'  'xtre'  'retle  105.0 (C)
1  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n'  'A'  'xtre'  'retla    0 (s*C)
2  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n'  'A'  'xtre'  'retla    0 (s*C)
```

EDIT:

Problem is there are some list with no lenght 2, so need filter it:

```
dataInList = [["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retle ",' 105.0 (C)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retla ",' 0 (s*C)\n'],
 ["'2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n', 'A', 'xtre','retla",' 0 (s*C)\n'],
 [ "aaa"]]

df = pd.DataFrame([[y.strip() for y in x[0].split(',') + [x[1]]] for x in dataInList if len(x) == 2])
print (df)
                           0    1       2       3          4
0  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n'  'A'  'xtre'  'retle  105.0 (C)
1  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n'  'A'  'xtre'  'retla    0 (s*C)
2  '2018-05-15 15:35:57\t\n'  'A'  'xtre'  'retla    0 (s*C)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, great approach. I'm however getting "IndexError: list index out of range", Is there a quick fix to this?

Comment: Thanks a million times!